# Nested Flatlist with Horizontal ListHeaderComponent Does not Scroll Inside Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a paged component in react native, where each page has a FlatList with ListHeaderComponent that could be scrolled. However, adding ListHeaderComponent does not make it scroll the list, only pages change.

ParentComponent:

```
const [currentPageIndex, setCurrentPageIndex] = useState(0);
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  const headerData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 100 }}>
      <View>
        <Text>Current Page: {currentPageIndex + 1}</Text>
      </View>
      <ScrollView
        nestedScrollEnabled
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        onMomentumScrollEnd={(e) => {
          const index = Math.round(
            e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / e.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width
          );
          setCurrentPageIndex(index);
        }}
      >
        <PageComponent data={data} headerData={headerData} />
        <PageComponent data={data} headerData={headerData} />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

PageComponent:

```
export function PageComponent({ data, headerData }) {
  const { sizeConstants, spacing } = useAppTheme()
  return (
    <View style={{ width: sizeConstants.screenWidth }}>
      <FlatList
        nestedScrollEnabled
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <FlatList
            horizontal
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItemHeader}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item}
          />
        }
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', marginTop: 20, marginHorizontal: 20, width: 100, height: 200 }} />
);

const renderItemHeader = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', marginVertical: 20, marginHorizontal: 10, width: 100, height: 20 }} />
);
```

all imports are from `react-native-gesture-handler`

why can i not scroll ListHeaderComponent horizontally and how to achieve it?

Comment: Instead of using Horizontal scrollview have a try by using Top Tab Bar from react navigation.

Comment: good idea! i will try, thanks